# Set a variable based off an input

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am looking to make a theme park ticketing program in tkinter, i have already made it in python 3 but i am trying to implement it into tkinter. However, I am unsure on how to set a variable based off a user input in tkinter. I want the program to ask the the user to input an integer for the amount of tickets they would like to buy, this would lead to a cost calculated from their input.

```
class PageAdultTickets(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="red")
        self.controller = controller
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="------------- Welcome to Fantasialand Ticket Station ------------", fg="Blue", font=controller.title_font)
        label1.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        label2 = tk.Label(self, text=f"The price of 1 adult ticket is £{adultTicket:0.2f}", fg="steelblue", bg="yellow", font=controller.title_font)
        label2.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=5)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Main Menu",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("MainMenu"))
        button1.pack(side="right")

        v = tk.IntVar()
        amAdultTickets = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=v)
        amAdultTickets.pack(side="bottom")
        s = v.get()
```

On a different note i would really appreciate it if you guys could help with how i can read a row from a csv file using a unique purchasing ID inside that row:

```
def searchingForFile():
  iUniqueID = int(input("What is the Unique ID of the past purchase?")
  with open("Purchases.csv", mode="rt", encoding='ascii') as f:
     spamreader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
     for row in spamreader :
        print(' '.join(row))
```

Comment: You have already used an `IntVar` `v`.  So what is your problem actually?

Comment: your `IntVar` has been setup correctly, but you need to add a method to retrieve it when called, rather than just adding `s=v.get()` during `__init__` which will always be default value `0`.

Comment: Please make sure only to ask about **1 problem per question**.